# Bag Class Implemented in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, data-structures, collections

I'm having to create a Bag class by using a collection (not Java's built in Collection). I'm having trouble figuring out the equal() method for this. Basically it needs to check if both bags are the same size, create copies for them, use a union to join them, and in a for loop check whether the current value is in each bag; if so, remove them. If both bags are empty then they are equal. For some reason the code keeps spitting out false?

I apologize for all the code, but it's hard to pinpoint what to leave out or not, since most of the code coincides.

Thanks for all of the help!!

EDIT: This also goes along with this question: [Building a bag class in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651105/building-a-bag-class-in-java)

```
public class Bag<t> implements Plan<t>{
private final int MAX = 10;
private final int DEFAULT = 6;

private static Random random = new Random();

private t[] content; 
private int count;


//Constructors
public Bag(){
    count = 0;
    content = (t[]) (new Object[DEFAULT]);
}
public Bag(int capacity){
    count = 0;
    if(capacity<MAX)
        content = (t[])(new Object[capacity]);
    else System.out.println("Capacity must be less then 10");
}


//Implemented Methods
public void add(t e) {
    try{
        if(!contains(e) && (!(size() == content.length))){
            content[count] = e;
            count++;
        }
        }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception){
            System.out.println("Bag is Full");
        }
}


public boolean isEmpty() {

    return count==0;        
}


public boolean contains(t e) {
    Object location = null;

    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
        if(content[i].equals(e)) location=i;

    return (location!=null);
}


public int size() {

    return count;
}


public void addAll(Bag<t> b) {
    for (int i=0;i<b.size();i++)
        add(b.content[i]);
}


public Bag<t> union(Bag<t> a, Bag<t> b) {
    Bag<t> bigBag = new Bag<t>();

    for(int i=0; i<a.size();i++)
        bigBag.add(a.content[i]);
    for(int k=0; k<b.size();k++)
        bigBag.add(b.content[k]);

    return bigBag;
}


public boolean equals(Bag<t> e) {
    Bag<t> bag1 = new Bag<t>();
    Bag<t> bag2 = new Bag<t>();
    Bag<t> bag3 = new Bag<t>();
    t object;

    if(size() == e.size()){
        bag1.addAll(this);
        bag2.addAll(e);

        bag3.union(bag1, bag2);

        for(int i=0; i<bag3.size();i++){
            object = bag3.content[i];
            if((bag1.contains(object)) &&(bag2.contains(object))){
                bag1.remove(object);
                bag2.remove(object);

            } 

        }
    }


    return (bag1.isEmpty()&&(bag2.isEmpty()));

}
```

Comment: "I'm having to create a Bag class by using a collection." where is collection in here?

Comment: That's kind of an inefficient way to compare the two. Is it a requirement you do it that way?

Comment: You might want to look at existing implementations such as Guava's [Multiset](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) and it's implementations source code [HashMultiset](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/HashMultiset.java) and [AbstractMapBasedMultiset](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/AbstractMapBasedMultiset.java) for idea on improving efficiency using a backing set instead of an array.

Comment: Well it is a requirement to compare the two like that unfortunately..
And by a collection i mean actually creating the collection myself, not the Java's built in Collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be in your union() method, or with how you're using it. Its actually returning a new Bag rather than adding bags `bag1` and `bag2` to `bag3` which is how `equals()` is expecting it to behave.

Do you know about class methods yet? This is what `union()` really is. Add the `static` keyword in the signature, like so.

```
public static Bag<t> union(Bag<t> bag1, Bag<t> bag2)
```

Now, let's fix the definition of the equals method. The `equals()` in the sample code has a signature of

```
public boolean equals(Bag<t> e)
```

But this should be

```
public boolean equals(Object o)
```

So we have to make sure `o` is a `Bag` first.

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    } else if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    } else if (!(obj instanceof Bag))
        return false;
    }

    Bag<?> other = (Bag<?>) obj;
    if (this.count != other.count) {
        return false;
    }

    Bag<t> bag1 = new Bag<t>();
    Bag<t> bag2 = new Bag<t>();
    bag1.addAll(this);
    bag2.addAll(other);

    // If you don't know about `static` yet, just use this instead of the following I guess 
    //Bag<t> bag3 = new Bag<t>();
    //bag3 = bag3.union(bag1, bag2);
    Bag<t> bag3 = Bag.union(bag1, bag2);

    t object;
    for(int i=0; i<bag3.size();i++) {
        object = bag3.content[i];
        if ((bag1.contains(object)) && (bag2.contains(object))){
            bag1.remove(object);
            bag2.remove(object);
        }
    }

    return (bag1.isEmpty() && (bag2.isEmpty()));
}
```

Fix a couple brace/compiler errors and I think this might work. I can't test it without the missing `remove()` method though.

Comment: For some reason Eclipse isn't accepting the static modifier for the method. 
Also the interface I have wont allow the changes to the equal() method, due to the assignment and its strict rules..

Comment: I figured it out, thank you very much! It was the assignment of bag 3. 
In my code it did not assign bag3 to bag3.union(bag1,bag2), so it should have been
    "bag3 = bag3.union(bag1,bag2)"

Comment: Yep, that was it. Feel free to upvote, if it helped. :) PS - the comment about changing the equals method is because you're trying to override equals() on the Object class, which has this signature: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)

Comment: Oh I understand what you were getting at now. It was a long day.
And I wish I could upvote, I would definitely if I didn't just create this account